# DNS reverting back to registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I host sites via HostGator. A friend bought a domain at Network Solutions. I went in to Network Solutions and change the DNS server to be my hosting DNS server.

I then went to check on his domain and for a while it still showed the Network Solutions landing page that happens when you buy a domain from them (same as when you buy from GoDaddy).

After a couple of hours, it still showed the Network Solutions landing page. So I checked on a different computer and could verify that the domain was pointing at my servers (my landing page).

SO I rebooted my main machine, then checked the domain and it was THEN coming up with my server, so I could start editing the HTML and working on the site.

I worked on this site for several hours last night. However, this morning I went to check the site and ONCE AGAIN, it was coming up as the Network Solutions landing page.

So again, I rebooted and it the domain is once again pointing correctly to my server.

BUT - just a couple minutes ago, as I was working on the site, WHAMO ... back to the Network Solutions landing page.

I tried to do an ipconfig /flushdns to see if that would fix the problem but it did not.

The domain is `tosaygoodbyemovie.com` - every computer/phone/kindle I've tested with shows the proper site EXCEPT my main work computer (the one I really need to show correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=whois&host=%20tosaygoodbyemovie.com

This is showing:

```
 Name Server: NS585.WEBSITEWELCOME.COM
 Name Server: NS586.WEBSITEWELCOME.COM
```

Both owned by Host Gator.

You may want to try and use public dns servers in the meantime to get work moving. If the problem persists, you might want to make sure your router isnt caching dns results.

Public servers:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Eureka!  This at least got me looking in the right place!  Argh!  I have a VPN for work that I connect to first thing in the morning.. it sometimes is buggy, goes up and down, when it does this, it sticks an old static DNS ip in my wireless ip4 settings.  Thus my issue...thank you for pointing me in the right direction!